# Using the Except clause for two DataTable objects

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-objects

I currently want to select various records from a DataTable object with various fields, but I want to exclude the records in which their CustomerID exists in another DataTable.  More or less like using the "Except" or "NOT IN" clause in SQL.  In SQL would be

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE CustomerID Not In (SELECT CustomerID FROM Table2)
```

I want to have the result set in another DataTable.

This is what I have:

```
var test = (from dt1 in lastMonthFunded.AsEnumerable() 
select new { CustomerId = dt1.Field<int>("CustomerId"), 
           LoanNumber =  dt1.Field<Int32>("LoanNumber") })
          .Except(from dt2 in lastYearFunded 
          select new {customerNum=dt2.Field<Int32>("LoanNumber")});
```

Visual Studio displays the following messages:

> Error 1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>
> Error 2   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Except(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: What's your exact problem?

Comment: Thanks John!  I missed that.  The query that I posted is not working for me.  Visual Studio throws the following message: Error 1 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Data.DataRow>' and

Comment: It also adds: Error 2 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Except<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Please add that information to your question, and show the line that the problems occur on.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your objects depends on IQUeryable or IEnumerable based class, you should be able to use Linq:

```
var test = from dt1 in lastMonthFunded
           where !(from d2 in LastYearFunded
                   select d2.LoanNumber).Contains(dt1.LoanNumber)
           select dt1;
```

With the above LINQ you will be able to get all lastMonthFunded records that are not present in LastYearFunded.

Comment: Please add an explanation of this code. Also, please say how you came up with that code. That will help this reader and future readers.